# VBA print a value in msg box

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck in an assignment for school, this is what i have to do:

This is the current code I have:

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. There is a reason you can't delete a post after having gotten answers, and trying to bypass that by defacing it is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop in the array you've loaded and :

```
Sub Ratio()

Dim OperatingRatio() As Double
Dim j As Long

With Sheets("Summary")
    OperatingRatio = .Cells("I80:M80").Value

    For j = LBound(OperatingRatio, 2) To UBound(OperatingRatio, 2)
        If OperatingRatio(1, j) > 100 Then
            MsgBox .Cells(14, 9 + j)
            .Cells(80, 9 + j).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
        End If
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @RobinBol : You are welcome! Just please take a minute to take the tour and learn how to accept answers and how the community works! ;) http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you loop through all cells individually, like this:

```
Dim i As Integer

'9 means column I and 13 is column M
For i = 9 To 13
    ' Getting the percent values
    Debug.Print Worksheets("Summary").Cells(80, i).Value
Next
```

This way you can continue by yourself.

Comment: @R3uk answered at the same time, he posted the full answer